# Xamarin Triggers XAML with "Any" condition. Can it be done without converter or VM properties controlling the UI?

Tags: xamarin, triggers

The simplest example would be a page with two checkboxes and a button. The button has two datatriggers, one bound to each checkbox's "IsChecked" property, and the setters both point to the "IsEnabled" property of the button. In my searching I found recommendations to set the "IsEnabled" property to false, and write a DataTrigger for each of your "or" conditions to set it to true. This is because the MultiTrigger uses the "AND" operator.

The binding is working, just not with the functionality I'm looking for. If CheckBox1 is checked then the button is enabled. If CheckBox2 is then checked, the button stays enabled. If CheckBox1 is then unchecked, the button is disabled. What are the approaches to keep the button enabled in this scenario since CheckBox2 is still checked?

It seems like this should be doable in XAML as it is only handling boolean properties on controls existing in the XAML and setting boolean values, but it appears we get the DataTrigger (if and only if) and the MultiTrigger (All conditions, so "AND"). Is there a way to write a trigger for "ANY of these conditions"?

Quick example XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" />
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox2" />
<Button Text="Submit" IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox1}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox2}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've moved on by setting VM properties for IsChecked on the checkboxes, and setting Command.CanExecute and calling Command.CanExecuteChanged() for the button's command.

I'm happy to continue the discussion though if anyone has any further ideas.

Comment: There are many different solution which can implement it , and don't forget to accept the answer , which will help more people :)

Comment: Will do, StackOverflow is preventing me for another 6 hours :)

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The "ANY" condition might be met with [`StateTriggers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#state-triggers) and [`CompareStateTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#compare-state-trigger). See also [VisualStateManager Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.5/4.5.0#visualstatemanager-target) for the use of `TargetName`.

Assuming the layout is `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox2" />
    <Button x:Name="button" Text="Submit" IsEnabled="False"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In `Resources`:

```
<Style TargetType="StackLayout">
  <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
    <VisualStateGroupList>
      <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
          <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <CompareStateTrigger Property="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox1}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="True" />
            <CompareStateTrigger Property="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox2}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="True" />
          </VisualState.StateTriggers>
          <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter TargetName="button"
                    Property="Button.IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
          </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
          <VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <CompareStateTrigger Property="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox1}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="False" />
            <CompareStateTrigger Property="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox2}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                 Value="False" />
          </VisualState.StateTriggers>
          <VisualState.Setters>
            <Setter TargetName="button" 
                    Property="Button.IsEnabled"
                    Value="False" />
          </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateGroupList>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note: In Xamarin.Forms [4.5.0.356](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.5/4.5.0#wednesday-february-26-2020---xamarinforms-450356-450) `StateTriggers` and `CompareStateTrigger` is experimental so the following must be added in `App.xaml.cs` (in the Xamarin.Forms project):

```
public App()
{
    Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "StateTriggers_Experimental" });
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. I implemented this to give it a shot. Conceptually I see how it should work, but in practice I do not get results. I tried with & without adding a two way binding then setting breakpoints on the getter/setter, and with / without putting a click event in the XAML and code behind with a breakpoint. The checkbox selections seemed to have no impact on my ability to hit a breakpoint. Also no error messages. So I'm not sure if it is the expirmental nature, or if I've coded something wrong on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **MultiTrigger** .

`MultiTrigger` behaves similarly to Trigger or DataTrigger but it has multiple conditions. All the conditions must be true for a Setters to fire

```
<Button Text="Submit" IsEnabled="True">  
    <Button.Triggers>
         <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
           <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox1}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
              <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference CheckBox2}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
           </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>

</Button>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, in my question I outlined the limitation that MultiTrigger has. If either checkbox is selected, I want the setter to fire. This mostly works with individual DataTriggers, but I can get into the scenario where I have a checkbox selected, and the button is disabled as outlined in the OP.